# What do we call someone who respects time?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering if there is a specific adjective for someone who respects time, who always comes on time and leaves in time, and someone who uses his time productively and meaningfully.

I have not found any terms which are suitable for that.

Comment: You should edit your question and give us some idea about how they 'respect' their time.  Do you mean use their time productively ?  perhaps call them "efficient"...do you mean they're always on time ? something like 'punctual'?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean, people who do both, people who are punctual and make use of their time productively and meaningfully.

Comment: They are prompt and efficient.  As for a single word that covers both...can't think of one.

Comment: *punctual*, *on time*, *never tardy*.

Comment: Sticking precisely to a schedule is entirely different from using time productively, which is entirely different from using time meaningfully.  A small percentage of extremely successful people manage to do all, but it often involves prioritizing one against the other, in which case meaningful is highest, then productive, and schedule compliance is last.  So if you really want all of those characteristics, punctual wouldn't cover it.  Can you make your definition more precise?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your clarifications in the comments, '[punctual](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/punctual)' would be best.

> > **adjective:** arriving, doing something, or happening at the expected or correct time; not late:

Comment: A punctual person might not use time productively and meaningfully, as the OP requests. I am unaware of a single word which means all of these things.